# Convert elements of list to string

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

how easily can I convert elements of this list to string.
If I have output like this:

```
{{M, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {A, 0, 0, 0}}
```

And I want something like this:

```
{{M, 1001110}, {A, 000}}
```

Or

```
{{M, "1001110"}, {A, "000"}}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
lis = {{M, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {A, 0, 0, 0}};
{First@#, StringJoin[ToString /@ Rest@#]} & /@ lis

(* {{M, "1001110"}, {A, "000"}} *)
```

Comment: Similarly, `{#1, StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {##2}} & @@@ lis`.

Comment: @march. That's a good one too.

Answer (score 8):

```
Cases[{{M, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {A, 0, 0, 0}}, {x_, y__} :> {x, 
   StringJoin[ToString /@ {y}]}]
```

Comment: Why RuleDelayed required?  (It is, I know; but why?)  For example, if the second pattern mapped to just `{y}`, it would not be required.

Comment: @Alan I assume to keep `y` from being shadowed by another variable named `y`

Answer (score 3):

```
Transpose[{a[[;; , 1]], StringJoin @@@ IntegerString @ a[[;; , 2 ;;]]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

If on the off chance you are seeking binary output for numbers then:

```
dat = {{M, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {A, 0, 0, 0}};
{First@#, BaseForm[FromDigits[Rest@#, 2], 2]} & /@ dat
```

[image]

Hope this helps.